# Sorting arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

What would be the best practice to sort a list containing date and a unique identifier for the date, like so:

```
20110101 5
20110101 78
20150305 103
```

(That is YYYYMMDD Unique identifier).

I have tried making arrays in php, amongst others:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20110101
            [order] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20120101
            [order] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => 20130101
            [order] => 1
        )
)
```

and

```
$data[] = array('date' => 20100101, 'number' => 122);
$data[] = array('date' => 20110123, 'number' => 120);
$data[] = array('date' => 20111212, 'number' => 123);
$data[] = array('date' => 20091212, 'number' => 121);
$data[] = array('date' => 20151212, 'number' => 100);
$data[] = array('date' => 20151212, 'number' => 99);
```

but I can't manage to get the PHP to print, well... anything using different sorting methods (like array_multisort).

What I would want to achieve is a list sorted by date and unique number. The second example would thus begin like:

```
20151212 100,
20151212 99,
20111212 123
```

I am mew and fresh to PHP, so please keep the answers at beginner level!

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sort by?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorting+multidimensional+array

Comment: Please show your code. The third example in the [`array_multisort` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) shows one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to attack the problem is by using a callback function to sort the entries by using [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a,$b){
  //do the necessary check if $a and $b conforms to your structure
  if($a['date'] < $b['date']) return -1;
  if($a['date'] > $b['date']) return 1;
  if($a['number'] > $b['number'] return 1;
  if($a['number'] < $b['number'] return -1;
  return 1;
}

usort($data,'cmp');
```

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed work. However looking further in to your solution I found the following: foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $date[$key]  = $row['date'];
    $number[$key] = $row['number'];
} . Which does the trick with even less code!

Answer (score 1):

> a unique identifier for the date

Then use the date as the key for the array and ksort it:

```
 $data = array(20100101 => 122
         , 20110123 => 120
         , 20111212 => 123
         , 20091212 => 121
         ....
```

OTOH if the nested array structure is being imposed on your code, then go lookup the many, many questions on how to sort a multi-dimensional [sic] array in PHP.

Comment: From the examples it seems that the same date can occur multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as Felix King noted the same date can occur multiple times. As it seems 'ksort' would bunch up similar dates and only display the one with the highest number, e.g. 20150101 => 10 and 20150101 => 30 would display as [20150101] => 30.

Comment: @Matte: "That is YYYYMMDD Unique identifier" - so not a unique identifier then. And ksort doesn't bunch them up, you can't create 2 array elements with the same key.

Comment: @symcbean, apologize for not explaining thoroughly enough. What I mean by "YYYYMMDD unique identifier" is that the date (YYYYMMDD) is followed by a unique identifier. With other words for the first example the the date would be 20110101 and the unique identifier for that row would be 5. Thus the same date might occur multiple times but always in connection to a unique identifier occuring only once.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. You can write your own function to sort the array as you wish. The examples should provide enough to go on.